# Creating new Token in Plaid (/link/token/create)

Tags: react-native, plaid

I am trying to integrate Plaid into an Expo app for the first time and am a bit confused on the integration process.

I have been following the following guides:

https://github.com/plaid/react-native-plaid-link-sdk

https://plaid.com/docs/link/link-token-migration-guide/

One thing that has been confusing for me is the process of generating a new token using "/link/token/create". What exactly does this mean and where do I perform "/link/token/create" in order to fetch this token?

Thank you!

edit:

As based on the first link, I have the following:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={styles.title}>Tab One</Text>
    <PlaidLink
    tokenConfig={{
      token: '#GENERATED_LINK_TOKEN#',
    }}
    onSuccess={(success: LinkSuccess) => {
      console.log(success);
    }}
    onExit={(exit: LinkExit) => {
      console.log(exit);
    }}
  >
    <Text>Add Account</Text>
  </PlaidLink>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out the [Quickstart](https://www.plaid.com/docs/quickstart)? It has a sample implementation showing how `/link/token/create` is used.

More fundamentally, your sample code is all frontend sample code. Plaid apps need both a frontend (to display Link) and a backend (to call the API) -- all Plaid API calls (including to `/link/token/create`) need to be made from the backend. When your user expresses an intent to link a Plaid account, your frontend should trigger the backend to call `/link/token/create`, and the backend should then pass that token to the frontend to be used in initializing Link.